Reference request: basis for subspace and sublattice defined for integer equations.
Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, which contains that lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Suppose I have an $r \times n$ matrix $B$ with integer entries $b_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ solving $Bx = 0$ form a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let's call this $S$. Also, the $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ solving $Bx = 0$ form a subgroup, which is $S \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.
I believe $S \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a lattice in $S$, and I would appreciate a reference that proves this.  To see this, it is sufficient to find a set $\mathcal{B} \subseteq S \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ which is an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $S$ and a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $S \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.
The first paragraph of this post claims the fact is true, but I would like to have a reference for this. Thanks in advance.

To show that $\mathcal{L} = S \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a lattice, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{L}$ satisfies the following two properties (refer this link)

$\mathcal{L}$ is closed under addition and subtraction - For $x, y \in \mathcal{L}$, we have $Bx = By = 0 \implies B(x-y) = 0$. Thus, $x - y \in \mathcal{L}$ because it is still an integer vector. Similarly, since $B(-y) = 0$, it follows that $B(x + y) = 0$, implying, $x+y \in \mathcal{L}$ as well.
$\mathcal{L}$ is discrete, i.e., there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall x, y \in \mathcal{L}, \|x-y\| \geq \epsilon$. This follows immediately, as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is already discrete.

